# ng-options not binding inside modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a modal dialog (ui bootstrap dialog) that displays some form fields for selection. when i select and click save, the binding are ok, i can see this from my browser dev tool bar. but when i open the modal again to edit the changes, the binding on the dropdown are lost, they all reset to the first option in the select list, if i look at my model from dev tools the correct values are there but not reflecting on the dialog display.

I have a directive 'display-paramaters' that handles the parameters display

```
(function(){

function displayParameters(){

    return{
        scope:true,
        restrict:'E',
        templateUrl:'app/templates/displayParameters.html',
        controller:function($scope,globalContainer){
            $scope.globals=globalContainer.variables;



        }

    }
}

angular.module("App").directive("displayParameters",displayParameters);
```

})();

The template is

```
<div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label class="control-label">{{mapping.CommandMappings[0].Field}}</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control hack" ng-model="mapping.CommandMappings[0].SourceType">
        <option value="1">Event</option>
        <option value="2">Variable</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <select ng-options="field for field in foundFields.entityOptions" class="form-control" ng-if="mapping.CommandMappings[0].SourceType==1" ng-model="mapping.CommandMappings[0].ValueSource">
    </select>

    <select class="form-control" ng-if="mapping.CommandMappings[0].SourceType==2" ng-model="mapping.CommandMappings[0].ValueSource"
            ng-options="variable.value as variable['name'] for variable in globals">
    </select>
</div>
```

I used it as so

```
   <tabset>
       <tab heading="Command Mapping">
           <div style="margin-top:5px">
               <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="mapping in commandMappings">
                   <display-parameters></display-parameters>
               </div>
           </div>
       </tab>
       <tab heading="Variable Mapping">

       </tab>
   </tabset>
```

Attached are also images of the dialog before initial select and save and later opening to edit selected options. Also images of the data structure i am binding to.
[First Time Dialog opens, i make selections and later clicks save](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-EaUAQOraRQLTRjVERuUEs5dWM/view?usp=sharing)

[Opens the dialog again but the bindings are gone, all reset to index 0](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-EaUAQOraRQRUt4Ym12aHc2bVk/view?usp=sharing)

[Inspects the object from console and find the binding is intact](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-EaUAQOraRQVmhEc1IyLUtlLWs/view?usp=sharing)

I do not know why i loose the binding on the view when the dialog opens the second time, but it is correct on the model

Comment: How can you say that inspecting the object that the bindings are intact? In your directive you are only binding to `SourceType` and `ValueSource`, and there respective values in that console inspect is `1` and `''`

Answer (score 0):

data  is saved into  mapping.CommandMappings[0].ValueSource  ,then  you close modal dialog which has a  controller,

when  you again  try to open it , modal dialog  related controller get initialize
&  also ( mapping.CommandMappings[0].ValueSource ={} ) get  initialized .

Comment: @Beyers sorry i posted this at night i have the correct console snapshot here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-EaUAQOraRQODJ3ckVoN01iWTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I get the data each time the modal opens from the controller